# Getting Middle Column Content to Center Properly

Tags: css, position, alignment, html

I'm tryign to create this page: http://ascendancyconsulting.com/Landings/ACConsult1.html
but I'm having issues getting things to center properly. I would liek to do this with out setting fixed widths if possible because I want it to scail somehwat iwth window size.

Notice what's happening:
1. The headline  is not centering itself in the "shell" div. 
2. The opt-in box ovlaps on the middle column when narrowing the window, instead of just stopping and creating a sideways scroll bar. 
3. The 3 badges/button at the bottom are supposed ot be horizonatly in line but one of them is displaying underneath; and they also (if possible) should move to the left as the window narrows instead of stopping when the hit the "left badges" div.

What changes do I need to make it get it to flow nicely? Does the div layout make sense or am I doing it wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this CSS to the inner div:

```
#MiddleColumn {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course, you don't have to set the width to 50%. Any width less than the containing div will work. The margin: 0 auto is what does the actual centering.

If you are targeting IE8+, it might be better to have this instead:

```
    #MiddleColumn {
         display: table;
         margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

It will make the inner element center horizontally and it works without setting a specific width.

Comment: if i helped you, then why dont you go ahead and accept my answer by clicking the check beside my answer and/or upvote my answer, Thanks

Comment: Thought I did. saw it go green, browser glitch perhaps.  Done now.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem is better if you look at Twitter Bootstrap.
It's a library that contains css files already set up so you can do things faster and they auto-resize and move around depending on the window width and so forth.

Have a look here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Next time also provide a code so that who looks at your problem can spot what the error is and doesn't have to make it up by himself.